# Is it possible to transform a whole number array (positive and negative) and a sum of a subset to a natural number (positive only) array and sum

Tags: arrays, math, mathematical-optimization, numeric, subset-sum

From my understanding, if I want to create a natural number (positive only) representation of a whole number (positive and negative) array, it is quite straight forward... take the absolute value of the smallest element in the array plus 1, and add it to each number in the array, this gives me a positive only array starting from 1 and maintaining the relevant distance between elements.

However, if I want to use this newly transformed array in a subset sum problem, my target sum will no longer be accurate.

I have found a work around, where by I add the factor used on the array, times by the number  of elements currently being considered as a subset to the sum.

However, this can cause false positives and also causes it to be more computationally complex.

Has anyone had success with a similar issue, or know of a more reliable approach.

Comment: If you added Z = 1 + abs(min(x_i)), to give yourself an all positive array y_i = x_i + Z, and you have the sum of a subset from i to j, S = sum_{k = i to j} y_k, then S' = sum_{k = i to j} x_k = S - Z(1+j-i), assuming j >= i. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @SimonGoater if your comment includes "does this answer you question", you wrote an answer, not a comment: please _post it_ as an answer =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The OP's own question appears to say much the same thing though in words, so I wasn't clear what he was asking....

Comment: What is the actual problem, you are trying to solve?